# Filter chain halted as :authenticate_with_token! rendered or redirected Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, auth-token

So I am working on a location-based api with rails where a location has many users and a user belongs_to a location at a particular time. This means the user table will contain a location_id column which serves as the foreign key. This, however, is different from most of the apps I have worked on in which the user will have many 'products' for example. So, I have this in my locations_controller.rb file

```
class Api::V1::LocationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_with_token!, only: [:create]
    respond_to :json

    def show
        respond_with Location.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        # @location = current_user.locations.build(location_params)
        @location = Location.new(location_params)
        current_user.location = @location
        current_user.save
        if @location.save
            render json: @location, status: :created, location: [:api, :v1, @location]
        else
            render json: {errors: @location.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    private


    def location_params
        params.require(:location).permit(:latitude, :longitude, :address)
    end
end
```

But I get the error

```
Started POST "/api/v1/locations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-20 10:05:50 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::LocationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"location"=>{"latitude"=>"2.23413", "longitude"=>"2.908019", "address"=>"Sims1 streets"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_with_token! rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

My Question is: How do I solve this? I have searched everywhere but all to no avail. Please help

My authenticable.rb file is

```
module Authenticable

  # Devise methods overrides. This finds the user by auth_token and it's sent to the server
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers["Authorization"])
  end

  def authenticate_with_token!
    render json: { errors: "Not authenticated" }, status: :unauthorized unless user_signed_in?
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    current_user.present?
  end

end
```

Comment: If `request.headers["Authorization"]` is empty or nil, it will log you in as the first user it finds that has no `auth_token` set. Make sure to check that `request.headers["Authorization"]` is not nil!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a callback befote the create action

```
before_action :authenticate_with_token!, only: [:create]
```

so whenever you will go to this action it will ask for a valid authentication token,the action will not be performed until a valid authentication token is provided.

As you can see in your console

```
 User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

The user auth token is null.

Please try sending a valid authtoken to authenticate user before craete action.

You might be having a auth_token column in your users table.
Try finding the authentication_token for any user and pass it in your url

i.e

```
 /api/v1/locations?user_token= your token
```

Comment: Please @kajalOjha, how do I go about it? I have been brainstorming on how to achieve that. Kindly help me out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check it now. I was actually doing /api/v1/locations?auth_token= your token  before now

Comment: Although it didn't work, I think the problem has to do with this line `def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers["Authorization"])
  end`. I need to see how I can tackle this

Comment: try debugging the issue what are you getting in request.headers["Authorization"]

Comment: Still no way. Maybe another approach to this will do. But finding another good way is an issue for me. Most tutorials are old

Comment: I think I have fixed the problem. I changed `auth_token: request.headers["Authorization"]` to `auth_token: params[:auth_token]` and that fixed it. Only that I need to rewrite my test again. Thank you @kajal

Comment: Make sure to check if `request.headers["Authorization"]` is not `nil`, before you query like that. :-)